# Image Not Moving Back To Correct Place

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview

I am trying to move an image back to a certain point on the screen. I am using the following code:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]; //Move To Start Position With Animation
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    plustwo.center = CGPointMake(36, 134);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

The problem is that the image does not back to the correct point on the screen. I am initiating this from an if statement that states:if this image collides with another image(PanGestureRecogizer) it moves back to its place. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if u did wrong?
As you didn't told the previous state of ur image if the co-ordinate you have given is the previous state then may be the u r using center here and image would have moved from origin, or if this code may not work.. so use this

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];  
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

and for more clear response, give clear question...